# How to add additional CSS to <code></code> tag?

Tags: css, wordpress, tags

I would be very grateful if someone could help me please.

I got to add an additional CSS code to the "code blocks", with the below code:

```
pre.wp-block-code {
border-left: 9px solid #F26C4F;
background-color: #1B325F !important;
padding: 15px;
```

But, I I need to edit also that  tags, i.e., for the inline code.

Let's say I am writing a paragraph and need to insert a piece of code inside of it, as for example "top command", when the top would have to be inserted between  `and` . So only the word "top" would be "printed" differently (with a custom background, for example).

How to achieve this, please?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the tags as selector, alternatively using p in addition.

Something like

```
p code {
  background: gray;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 0.15em 0.35em;
  white-space: normal;
}
```